# Total Internal Reflection in Quantum World

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I was thinking when a light beam falls at the interface of a medium with angle more than critical it undergoes TIR But in the quantum world, the electrons present on the edge would absorb it then when they release it how do they know they have to release the photon in an inward direction...

Comment: You could extend this question, (or rather  look for answers, as I am sure it, and the one below, has been asked)  to the question, how does the principle of least time operate on the quantum level? How does light reflect of a mirror, while respecting Snell's law on a classical level?

Comment: This is a very good question, normally the interaction between quantized light and quantized matter is a topic of Quantum Optics. Perhaps someone knowledgeable in this particular domain can answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

In classical electromagnetism total internal reflection produces an evanescent field that decays exponentially with distance into the medium from which the light is being reflected, see Section 9.2.3 of the [Electromagnetics and Applications](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-013-electromagnetics-and-applications-spring-2009/readings/MIT6_013S09_chap09.pdf) course from MIT or a textbook on electromagnetism like the ones recommended in [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/142419/recommended-books-for-advanced-undergraduate-electrodynamics).

In quantum mechanics the amplitude of the wave function decays exponentially in the medium from which the light is being reflected and so the probability of a photon being found at some distance into the medium also decays exponentially. For a detailed discussion see [Herbert Winful's review paper on tunnelling time](http://winful.engin.umich.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/376/2018/01/physics_reports_review_article__2006_.pdf).

Answer (score -1):

There are two ways to think about effects in the quantum world. You can either think of light/electrons as particles or as waves.

While you are correct to say that in a classical model, the light should scatter in a stochastic matter, in the quantum model, the photon is a wave that interacts with a probability distribution of an electron.

Comment: Does that really answer the question? Maybe a few more details needed? I say this to try and avoid downvotes....