# Best books for Electromagnetism?

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations

I would like to know some titles of the best books in Electromagnetism. Some poeple recommended me to read Griffiths.
My big deal is to become a theoretical physicist in Particles/Fields and Gravitation, so if you know a more rigorous book and self clear, please tell me!

Comment: This will depend on your current level of knowledge in maths and physics.  THere's no "best" book for everyone either.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommended books for advanced undergraduate electrodynamics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142419/)