# Book suggestion for a Math student taking Electromagnetism

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, education

I'm hoping to double major in math and physics. I'm currently taking graduate math courses and undergrad physics courses.

I'm having a really hard time with my Electromagnetism class. A lot of the problems being given have solutions that aren't really detailed enough for me to make sense of them. They will write down the setup of the question like it is second nature, and then just go to the math. A great example is when they have said, "The 'horizontal' components cancel." Not only do they have "horizontal" in quotes, but they don't even show what is canceling. So I have no idea what they are referring to here or what cancels. So if I come upon a problem where "horizontal" doesn't cancel, I have no idea how to approach it.

Does anyone know of a good mathematical Electromagnetism book? One that really goes explains each problem mathematically and doesn't cut out parts without explaining them mathematically?

Comment: Is the electromagnetism class intro-level, or is it primarily taken by third- and fourth-year physics majors?  What is the recommended/required textbook for the class?

Comment: Maybe [**Div, Grad, Curl, and All That**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0393925161) for theory and [**Schaum's Outline in Electromagnetics**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0071831479) for worked problems.

Comment: I asked on the math stack exchange because I understand physics better through mathematics. I would prefer a math-focused textbook. On a physics stackexchange I'm afraid they'd suggest physics books while I want a math book. It is a first course in electromagnetism. A 4000 level.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142419/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 1):

Somo classic (“old but gold”) books are:

- **Introduction to Electrodynamics**, by *David Griffitiths.* [He has a really nice introduction to Vector Calculus (The required for Physics) before starting the actual physics of electromagnetism.]
- **Classical Electrodynamics**, *Jackson* (another classic.)
- **The Feynman Lectures on Physics**, by *Richard Feynman* (which is other master piece in Physics.)

You may also be interested in some online resources that explores undergrad electromagnetism, like the *Walter Lewin’s Lectures.*

In the link https://youtu.be/rtlJoXxlSFE you find a whole list of lectures on electromagnetism.

Hope this material is useful!

Answer (score 0):

You have asked for good mathematical electromagnetism book. Below mentioned books are mathematical in their style.

1.**Classical electricity and magnetism**
Textbook by Wolfgang K. H. Panofsky

This is a advanced Undergraduate book  and its more inclined on mathematical side and well supplemented with theory.

2.**Modern Electrodynamics**
Textbook by Andrew Zangwill

An engaging writing style and a strong focus on the physics make this comprehensive, graduate-level textbook unique among existing classical electromagnetism textbooks. Charged particles in vacuum and the electrodynamics of continuous media are given equal attention in discussions of electrostatics, magnetostatics, quasistatics, conservation laws, wave propagation, radiation, scattering, special relativity, and field theory.

3. **Principles of electrodynamics**
   Textbook by Melvin Schwartz

Suitable for advanced undergraduates and graduate students, this volume offers a superb exposition of the essential unity of electromagnetism in its natural , relativistic framework while demonstrating the powerful constraint of relativistic invariance.Its a thin book and quite mathematical.

4.
**Classical Electrodynamics**
Textbook by John David Jackson

only for advanced students. Not an introductory text.The book is notorious for the difficulty of its problems, and its tendency to treat non-obvious conclusions as self-evident.