# Problem-solving books on electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electromagnetic-radiation, resource-recommendations, education

What are the best books on the problem-solving of classical electrodynamics exercises?

I looking for books that help me to solve Jackson and Griffiths exercises, i.e. books on the problem-solving of related exercises, i.e., the same exercises in a slightly different form.

Comment: "I'm looking for books that help me to solve Jackson and Griffiths exercises." What do you mean by that? Of course, these books themselves help you solve their exercises. You can find a solution manual for them if you want to see the solution.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I mean books on the problem-solving of related exercises, i.e., the same exercises in a slightly different form.

Comment: Try Electricity and magnetism by  Purcell

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142419/2451 and links therein.