# Asking for recommended mathematical basics to cover to master Electromagnetic theory

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, education

I was trying to self read **"Electrodynamics by Griffiths"**. However, I find it very difficult when different coordinate systems were used simultaneously. `Specially in Electrostatics and Magnetostatics.` I found out that I do not understand the mathematical calculations because of the skipped steps. Furthermore, `sudden transformation of coordinate systems` added more complexity on top of that.
`Specially the directions of 'E' and 'B' fields, their cross products, sudden change in coordinate systems with directions etc.` Therefore, I am seeking your suggestions to ground up *(a video lecture will be extremely helpful)* my mathematical background so that I can master Electromagnetic Theories *(specially various types of problem solving)*. I need it very badly because I am enrolled in a graduate school and without deep understanding of the basics I might fall in trouble.

**Note**: *I have gone through the first chapter of the Griffiths book, however that doesn’t help.*

Comment: Are you familiar with cylindrical and spherical coordinates?

Comment: I think that one of the math tools you should have learned prior to embarking on Griffiths text is vector calculus.  Usually as part of such a course in Calculus you learn about vector transformations from one coordinate system to another.  Such transformations can be from one cartesian coordinate system (e.g. x,yz) to another and often accomplished by a rotation matrix.  Other transformations can be from Cartesian coordinates to Spherical Coordinates or Cylindrical which are very common in an E&M course.  This is something you should study first.

Comment: Yes I am. However, the abrupt jumps troubling me to visualize what is happening. Hence, I am puzzled out every time. :(

Comment: @Hossain -- it would be better to give a detailed example of these abrupt jumps.  Maybe referencing the edition of the Griffiths text and page number, etc.

Comment: @K7PEH I knew the basics and the transformations. However, the change in coordinate systems, with that the change of directions of fields etc. and apply them to solve problems is very difficult for me. Even the solved examples is seems puzzling to me!

Comment: @K7PEH Griffiths 4th edition. Page 371 Example 8.4.

Comment: OK, rewrite your question and specifically point out where you have a problem with the published solution.  The more detailed, the better answer you are likely to get.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142419/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

Although my textbook, "Classical Electromagnetism", is at a higher level than Griffiths, the first two chapters coordinate the vector calculus with the physics, and could lead you into using vector calculus.