# Electromagnetism textbook

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, education

I'm in the market for a textbook dealing with classical electromagnetism for someone who already knows the basics (e.g. up to the derivation of the Maxwell equations and the basic expressions for electromagnetic waves). I'd like a well-written book that is rigorous and rooted in vector calculus but also provides intuition, and which describes both electrodynamics in free space and within circuits and conductive materials. Problems at the end of every chapter are ideal, and problems with solutions are even better. I plan to study this book independently and will not have access to an instructor. For reference, [here](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevApplied.6.014017) is a link to the kind of article that I would like to understand after reading this book. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: JD Jackson is the first thing to try

Comment: Julian Schwinger's "Classical Electrodynamics" textbook is a pretty interesting alternative to Jackson.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/142419/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'd like a well-written book that is rigorous and rooted in vector calculus

The book you want for that will be the [Classical Electrodynamics by JD Jackson](https://archive.org/details/ClassicalElectrodynamics2nd)

He provides an excellent tour starting from the electrostatics and employs techniques like Green's function technique to solve for generalized cases not only this book will lead to you profound understanding of Electrodynamics but of special relativity as well, and radiations and how radiations are produced.

Along with this book you can follow
[Introduction to Electrodynamics by D.J. Griffiths](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Electrodynamics) While in J.D. Jackson you'll find complete description through mathematics, this book on the other hand takes you on a tour with vector as well as component vise derivation, and the explanations in this book are very much intuitive.

So It would be better to follow the combination of the two.